# Web scraping a site with javascript using vba

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get some data from a site that doesn't change its url between its pages but run javascript to change the html page. What I need to do is to click in a button and in the new page I put initial date and final date to search the data I want. When I run this code below, the code doesn't recognize the new page charged on the screen.

The code that I hava until now:

```
 Public Sub test()
 Dim Col As Long, Row As Long
 Dim rawNum As String
 Dim JavaString As String
 Dim ie As Object
 Dim ObjCollection As Object

my_url = "https://www.selic.rtm/portal-selic/"
Row = ActiveCell.Row
Col = 4 'column with phone number
rawNum = Cells(Row, Col).Value

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate my_url

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "SelicPortal.navegacao.ir('/portal-selic-servicos/pesquisa-resultado-leilao.jsp')"

For i = 0 To 10
    Debug.Print ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(i).Name
Next i

End Sub
```

How can I put value into new inputs present in the new html charged by the javascript execution?

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: _www.selic.rtm unexpectedly closed the connection._

Comment: not exactly, but the html changes just on the screen and i cant access the new html updated by the javascript execution